# Selenium with Firefox: FirefoxProfile stops working when used a second time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to use selenium with firefox to create a profile of a browser I want to use repeatedly. I start by loading it up with extensions I want it to have, then call a function with that profile as a parameter to use for scraping.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension(extension='extension/1/path')
profile.add_extension(extension='extension/2/path')


def sele_scrape(profile,url):

  options = Options()
  options.headless = True

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,options=options,executable_path='path/to/geckodriver')

  driver.get(url)
  source=driver.page_source
  driver.quit()


sele_scrape(profile,'url1')
sele_scrape(profile,'url2')
```

It doesn't matter what order the urls are in, or what urls I use. The second one always causes this error:

```
File "(the python file for this project)", line 37, in <module>
    sele_scrape(profile,'url2')
  File "(the python file for this project)"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,options=options,executable_path='path/to/geckodriver')

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 166, in __init__
    capabilities.update(options.to_capabilities())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/options.py", line 180, in to_capabilities
    opts["profile"] = self._profile.encoded
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 173, in encoded
    self.update_preferences()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 102, in update_preferences
    self._write_user_prefs(self.default_preferences)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 226, in _write_user_prefs
    with open(self.userPrefs, "w") as f:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/8j/lrckmwqs5bs9b4srrjbj6r5c0000gn/T/tmpiluv90lz/user.js'
```

This line

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/folders/8j/lrckmwqs5bs9b4srrjbj6r5c0000gn/T/tmpiluv90lz/user.js'
```

Is particularly bizarre to me because I have no what its trying to refer to or why.

Any help, or even just a direction that I can look in, would be much appreciated!

Comment: if you want to use it repeatly then maybe create `driver` only once and don't `quit()` it.

Comment: probably when you `quit()` then it removes profile - and you would have to create again profile.

Comment: code works for me if I use `close()` instead of `quit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably when you `quit()` then it removes profile - and you would have to create again profile.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# --- functions ---

def sele_scrape(url):

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    #profile.add_extension(extension='extension/1/path')
    #profile.add_extension(extension='extension/2/path')
    
    options = Options()
    #options.headless = True
    
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)#,executable_path='path/to/geckodriver')
    
    driver.get(url)
    source = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()

# --- main ---

sele_scrape('https://stackoverflow.com')
sele_scrape('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

---

Code works correctly if I use `close()` instead of `quit()`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# --- functions ---

def sele_scrape(url, profile, options):
   
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)#,executable_path='path/to/geckodriver')
    
    driver.get(url)
    source = driver.page_source
    driver.close()

# --- main ---

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
#profile.add_extension(extension='extension/1/path')
#profile.add_extension(extension='extension/2/path')

options = Options()
#options.headless = True

sele_scrape('https://stackoverflow.com', profile, options)
sele_scrape('https://stackoverflow.com', profile, options)
```

---

Frankly, if profile should be reused then I would create `driver` only once and I would skip `close()`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# --- functions ---

def sele_scrape(url, driver):
   
    driver.get(url)
    source = driver.page_source

# --- main ---

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
#profile.add_extension(extension='extension/1/path')
#profile.add_extension(extension='extension/2/path')

options = Options()
#options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)#,executable_path='path/to/geckodriver')

sele_scrape('https://stackoverflow.com', driver)
sele_scrape('https://stackoverflow.com', driver)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely works, but I have questions about your suggested implementation. First, doesn't .close simply close the open tab, while quit closes the browser entirely? But if I load extnesions, don't they open other tabs that stay open after .close? That's what chrome does anyway

Comment: Second, I'm curious about your idea of not closing. To clarify, my program doesn't just scrape a bunch of urls one after another. Instead, it runs for a long time, then occasionally calls a selenium scraper. In that case, if I don't use .quit or .close, won't I have a firefox window open the whole time while I do other stuff, which is a bit wasteful? Do you think that not closing firefox would increase my speed of execution? Because I'm trying to optimize that as much as possible

Comment: if you don't quit then browser is all time in memory but it doesn't need few seconds to start browser again. When you run many urls in selenium then it can be useful to keep it open. If you use it occasionally then maybe you will no see difference but still it can run few seconds (or maybe minutes) shorter.